# Consume POST API call using javaee-api

Tags: java, java-ee-7

I am trying to hit a POST call using Plain Old Java Object wrapped with `Entity.json`. I am using the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>7.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here's how my POST function is:

```
public String testPostCall(TestParams params) {
        return target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                     .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                     .post(Entity.json(params), String.class);
    }
```

I think the problem is in `Entity.json(params)`. The error that I get is:

`javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: No message body writer has been found for class TestParams`.

Here's how my `TestParams` class looks like:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class TestParams {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Is there a missing dependency for converting POJO class `TestParams` to JSON? Or am I using wrong annotations? I want to consume an API which serves mostly POST calls. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to convert a POJO into a JSON from [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-java-object-to-json-string-using-jackson-api/) and then used the following code:

```
public String testPostCall(TestParams params) {
        try {
            return target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .post(Entity.json(mapper.writeValueAsString(params)), String.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```